# How to do Role based Authorization in ASP.net MVC 2.0 Application with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, authorization, windows-authentication

I am working on ASP.net MVC 2.0 Web Application in C#.

I am very new to MVC . I wanted to implement  Windows Authentication and Role based 
Authentication in my application.

I was sucessful in implementing windows authentication. I have configured Properly to make my application work with windows authentication.

**Code:**

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
```

So, from Windows Active directory i was able to get the logged in user name.

Then in the Session_Start of my application , i am sending that username to database whether

that particular is a valid user for that Application.

Now, Here i only have two roles: **Normal user and Admin**

So, a normal user should be restricted to only some set of pages.

I have database table structure like this: Sample Data Example

```
  UserID  IsAdmin

       1    false

       2    true

       3    false
```

I have read  many articles on this. But, after reading all those i was pretty much confused about the approach to be followed.

How can i create my custom Authorize Attribute to restrict the access and hiding the contents of page.

Please give some ideas / sample examples on this.

NOte:  I am working  MVC 2.0 Application